# duplicate value for resource 'attr/tint' with config

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have failed to build the android project which can be built successfully.

Build: Sync

> ../../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar/079f027781f9663d188d9dd5f4f897cd/res/values/values.xml
>       error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tint' with config ''. 
>       error: resource previously defined here.

The whole output:

> build failed   6s 89ms
>   Run build   5s 902ms
>   Load build  27ms
>   Configure build 3s 955ms
>   Calculate task graph    31ms
>   Run tasks   1s 871ms
>   null
>   Fell back to English for the following translations:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   null
>   ../../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar/079f027781f9663d188d9dd5f4f897cd/res/values/values.xml
>   error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tint' with config ''. 
>   error: resource previously defined here.

And here is my dependency.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'appboy_release', ext: 'aar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':strings')
    implementation project(':osp-core')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:0.6.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.7.1@aar'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation project(':loading-widget')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

It occurs when I update the Android studio to 3.1 and update the gradle plugin to 3.1.0 and gradle version 4.4 `(distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip).`

Before I can build it successfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try cleaning before you build?

Comment: use multidexenable

Comment: @ReazMurshed yes, I have tried, but still failed.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta it is being set unfortunately.

Comment: Delete entire *build folder (which is under *app folder) and clean+rebuild project again.

Comment: @Radhey It does not work. Does it work for you?

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Yashasvi not yet.

Comment: I was able to solve this actually. Search in your project. You'd have sth like: `<attr name="tint" format=...... />`. You've to rename that.

Comment: @Yashasvi
thanks, I will try that later. I guess it is the right answer, but do you know why I cannot do that, is there any document?
I have a custom view, and I define the attribute with tint.

Comment: I think it's a bug with gradle plugin. Need to confirm though

Answer (score 5):

For people still not able to solve this:

Search in your project. You'd have sth like:

`<attr name="tint" format=...... />` (mostly for a custom view).

You've to rename that attribute name and it should compile after that.

Comment: I have the same problem and have no tint attribute declaration in my code. I suspect that one of compiled libraries contains it. Is there any way to find out which one?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be creating a new values folder name `values-v21` then put your `attr.xml` file or that XML file that causing an error inside that folder so that it will not merge or confuse what attribute to be used. But of course, by doing this you are saying that this attribute will work or use only starting from SDK 21 and above something like that depends on what version you will choose.